# Different view of map on google.com than on own website

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the JS for the google map integrated in our website. It works without problems. When using google.com/maps and zoom into our Adress I can see our Hotel listed as Hotel. When looking to th map on our website there are only a few entries. How can I change to be on the "website-map" too?

[image: direkt from the google.com/maps]

[image: view in our website]

I looked around the mapoptions but didn't found a reverence which seems to solve the problem.

Comment: The details Google give on the maps on their own site differ from the details they provide to people using the API.  Instead what you should probably do is add a Marker where your property is

Comment: Oh, that's sad. I've a marker (our Logo shown in the lower screenshot). Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to force the display of a specific POI programmatically.

But of course you may place your own marker at this location.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've placed a marker created from our Logo to show the location. I wondered why some POI are set without any context (privat companies, authorities but not all and of different type...)